# Crawling links on a page, then visiting and inspecting each link with node and zombie.js

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I'm trying to build a simple utility in Node with zombie.js to visit a page, find and open all links on the page, and ensure that each child page returns a 200 successfully.

Here's an example of this code (written in CoffeeScript), crawling the home page of stackoverflow.com

```
Browser = require('zombie')

browserOpts =
  runScripts: false
  site: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'

home = new Browser browserOpts

home.visit '/', (e, browser) ->
  questions = browser.queryAll '#question-mini-list .summary h3 a'
  for q in questions
    qUrl = q.getAttribute 'href'
    page = new Browser browserOpts
    page.visit qUrl, (e, browser, statusCode, errors) ->
      console.log "Arrived at page #{browser.window.location} and found " + browser.html().length + " bytes"
      console.log statusCode
      browser.dump()
      return
  return
```

If you attempt to run this code, you'll notice the first handful of links are loaded correctly, and the number of bytes in the page is displayed.

However, after the first batch of successful page loads (the size of which seems random), all subsequent page loads seem to execute the callback to `visit` prematurely. The document is empty (it's just `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`) and the `statusCode` argument to the callback is `undefined`.

I can't explain or figure out why this is happening. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

excuse my js to a coffeescript question

```
var async = require('async');
var Browser = require('zombie');

var browserOpts = {
  runScripts: false,
  site: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
};

var home = new Browser(browserOpts);

home.visit('/', function(e, browser) {
  var questions = browser.queryAll('#question-mini-list .summary h3 a');
  async.eachLimit(questions, 3, function (question, cb) {
    var qUrl = question.getAttribute('href');
    var page = new Browser(browserOpts);
    page.visit(qUrl, function(e, browser, statusCode, errors) {
      console.log(("Arrived at page " + browser.window.location + " and found ") + browser.html().length + " bytes");
      console.log(statusCode);
      browser.dump();
      cb(e);
    });
  }, function (err) {
    console.error('OOPS', err);
  });
});
```

try it out here: http://runnable.com/UWh05t96qlJ8AAAC

You're making too many requests at once and stackoverflow is cutting you off.  It's cuttoff is 4 as far as I can tell.

If you really need data from stackoverflow use the api: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! The question uses crawling stackoverflow.com to demonstrate usage, but my original intent was to crawl another site entirely (the sales on www.totsy.com), and not actually to crawl the stackoverflow homepage. I don't think they are throttling, because I experience the same behaviour when crawling totsy.com.
However, this solution does seem to work. I'm thinking by throttling requests, you're preventing some kind of race condition. Ultimately, I suspect there are deeper issues at play here.

Comment: Yeah the cutoff limit of 3 may just be what zombie can handle at once.